Do we have enough samples to tell if miracles exist?
By miracles I means events that affected history, but happened not as a chain of events that statistically should in some time happened anyway ore make sense to happen finally.
Like the apple falling on Newton's head, we know that the apple may fall due to gravity, but maybe this apple fell as result of a miracle. This event can be explained, but the point is that the same event that has an explanation can happen due to some other reason, such as god's hand.
The question is whether we have enough samples from each event to tell that it makes sense that it finally happened, or whether we live in a chaotic system which make it only possible to predict things to the short run.
For instance, an apple fell on Newton's head. We know that the apple can fall due to gravity but it doesn't mean god can make it fall. Just because we know that amperic results can explained in some way,does it mean that we should assume that all events are results by nature's axioms?
Did anyone even tested. Why are people saying (me included), "I am sure there's a reasonable explanation to such a phenomenon" why we assume that. Just because something's can be explained by a statstical model, it doesn't means all of them can.

The universe exploded into existence (or always existed, or has cycled endlessly forever) 13.8 billion years ago. Matter came into existence. The sun and the earth came into existence. Life evolved. Humans evolved. Your parents met and procreated. You are here. What is the prior probability of your existence? Virtually zero. Yet here you are. You are a miracle. One need not adopt a theological viewpoint to see miracles. One only needs to look around. My lungs evolved to process the atmosphere and sustain my life. Another miracle. What are the odds!

@user4894 The odds of present-day species having evolved a thing that allowed them to survive is 100%. They did. The ones that didn't evolve that died and aren't here in the present day. Like if you ask someone to roll some dice, and to repeatedly reroll any values 1-3. Later, you look at the dice and see that all values are 4-6. Pretty unsurprising, really.

@NotThatGuy That's the post probability. I talked about the prior probability. Not sure why you missed that.

@user4894 You don't know the prior probability. You especially don't know the prior probability of God existing, which is required for Bayesian probability analysis. You can have your abstract and circular probability arguments which can get you to any number of contradictory conclusions based on what you're analysing. I'll stick to well-demonstrated and reliable scientific facts.

@user4894 Either you use "miracle" to refer to a god, which I addressed. Or you use "miracle" to merely refer to something unlikely, which is a meaningless claim (or it's an intellectually dishonest attempt to argue for a god). Although I addressed that too. Even if I misunderstood what you said (which I didn't), it's extremely disrespectful and inappropriate and not constructive to accuse someone of lying over that.

@user4894 If you mean unlikely things, then yes, unlikely things happen all the time. That's a meaningless claim (and I already pointed that possibility out, yet you act like I didn't...). And I don't confuse the issue by referring to those using the same term ("miracle") that people use for the actions of a magic space wizard. If you mean things that give you the warm fuzzies, then I don't see any meaningful truth statement in that.

Miracle: 100 Billion Humans Served. Horror: about half probably died from mosquito-borne illness. It's both.

Good luck distinguishing between an unexplained event that may be explainable if and when we have more data about what actually happened, misreporting or misunderstanding, and an event which is confirmed to be outside all mundane explanation, I would only grant the latter as miracles, and they're just isn't evidence to demonstrate any such to those who are skeptical. As I have said elsewhere, I cannot imagine any evidence that would convince me of a deity's intervention; I just would not except that conclusion if my mind is functioning as it is now. Others, obviously, feel differently.

@user4894 my point is that you're sure that all things that happened are outcome of other but how can you be sure without testing it why people saying "there is must be reasonable explanation" just because they know other things have one

@daniel: If you can propose a viable test, do so. The way you have posed things provides no path to an answer that isn't an unsupported assertion. Mu.

(typo, of course: accept, not except. I take exception to the constraints on editing comments, but I have to accept that they aren't going to change.)

@daniel I edited the post. My guess is that English is your second language.  Good job!

I am not certain what definition you are using for "miracle", but it seems like you might be attempting to connect two mutually exclusive concepts. On one hand, you seem to be using a system which presumes that all meaningful proof comes from what can be demonstrated, ostensibly by replication. On the other hand, you seem to be talking about things which might be meaningful, but cannot be be demonstrated, such as by replication. The two models cannot exist together as each axiomatically refutes the other.
I cannot speak in general for what people consider miracles to be, but from a Christian perspective, the concept of a "miracle", at least from the original languages means nothing of that sort. It does not mean "unprovable" or "unable to be understood", but simply means either (two different words are translated) "sign" or "ability". In the Bible, the source of Christian belief about miracles, they were never intended to be things which had any particular relationship one way or another with having their root causes identified empirically (this demand did not exist in that time before the Enlightenment movement). Instead, they were simply mean to be observable facts which seemed to indicate that the person giving a message had a special relationship with some force or ability beyond what a normal person, such as a pure con artist, would have access. They do seem to have some expectation that the events are beyond what could alternately be explained by mere luck or coincidence, but that doesn't imply that the cause could not be knowable.
Consider that if I were a man with a gun visiting an uncivilized population that had never heard of a gun. If I shot and killed somebody or something, the spectator would not have to presume that the gun had no known empirical and replicatable cause, or alternately affirm that it had such a cause, in order to know that I have some ability such that he should probably be careful not to make me mad. In that sense, this ability would be a sign that I'm not just another local dressed funny, thus, a "miracle" in the sense of the original words, and yet something which is very understandable by science and reason.

Well done. It's called polysemy-games. Or playing Humpty Dumpty after Lewis Carrolls character. Etymologically miracle means wonderful. All this natural/supernatural verify/unproven etc disputations are just post hoc wrangling

I think this answer is good, but the analogy with the gun could be improved by emphasizing the parallel implied dualism: Prophet-God, Rifleman-Industry. I missed it on the first reading.

"... a historically English-speaking perspective, which means a Christian perspective." After that remark, all of us Jews are looking at you funny.

@JonathanZ I had deleted that comment while you were typing your reply since I no longer think it's relevant or useful here. If you want to discuss it, we can make a chat.

If you had said it was "inaccurate", then I would obviously just delete my response to your comment. But if people think "English speaking" = "Christian", then I think that's a useful thing for other readers to know.

Let’s define a miracle as:

An event in nature purposefully caused (partially or fully) by a conscious agent not bound by the laws of nature, such that this event would not have been expected to occur under the normal operation of those laws.

In other words, if the agent had not intervened, we should not expect such an event to occur under the same prior conditions. That is, if we consider those conditions as initial inputs and apply the laws of nature, the event should not be expected to occur.
Do we have enough samples to infer the existence of miracles?
Technically, you only need one confirmed sample of X to establish that X exists. For example, finding a single black swan is sufficient to prove that black swans exist. So, asking for "enough samples" in plural doesn't really make much sense unless you are framing the question in a probabilistic Bayesian sense—where you are not entirely sure if a given sample is genuinely a miracle. In that case, having more samples might in principle help build a probabilistic argument that at least one of those candidate miracles is indeed a true miracle. If that’s what you mean, then it seems to me your question essentially boils down to a duplicate of the one I asked here: Can Bayes' theorem be used non-fallaciously to argue for miracles?
In short, all Bayesian approaches to arguing for miracles, God, or the supernatural face the challenge of defining priors and ruling out alternative explanations. Consequently, setting an objective threshold for how many witnesses, or reports, or cases are sufficient to establish, for instance, that Jesus resurrected or that miracles are real, is pragmatically impossible. Ultimately, it comes down to subjective judgment calls and private personal experience, and what you find compelling may not necessarily convince others.
By the way, if you’re looking for the strongest case for miracles supported by a large number of alleged examples, consider Craig S. Keener’s book Miracles.

So 'miracle' is like a nonce word: someone can use it to mean whatever they want. Humpty Dumpty would be pleased :-)

@ScottRowe I don't think the definition I suggested is too controversial.

My point in miracle is un unlikely event that effected history the questions about the samples is wather this event starcitsly should have happened some time or bot

The point is that is event that effected history which was unlikely to happened. But just because the event we know are outcome of bature rules such as dropping a ball it doesn't means that all events are kike that it possible to say that some ball may fall as results of god actions even tho we may find that they may fall due gravity

@daniel: with that definition, it is impossible to argue that any given event is, or is not, a miracle.

@keshlam it possible to  say that all events that happened are stacticly makes sense.

@Daniel: everything that actually happened does make sense. The question is what sense you want to make of it. If anything could be a miracle, the word miracle loses its meaning.

@keshlam but how do you know that everything that happened made sense , or we only assume it. Maybe if you look on the chances that the event that happened to happen is very small therefore the current situation was not only chains of events

You can hypothesize counterfactuals all you like.  That will not convince anyone except, possibly, yourself. You are making an assertion, not presenting an argument, not presenting facts, not presenting rationale. That isn't discussion, or philosophy.


Do we have enough samples to tell if miracles exist?

No. Not even close.
A "sample" must be a verifiable instance of a miracle.
Since miracles can't be reproduced and, by definition, are events that can't be explained by science, you have no concrete examples of a miracle that will survive scientific interrogation.
Finally, "miracles" are both rare and subjective. Finding a potato in my garden that looks exactly like Jesus is not evidence of a miracle.

Never mind the fact that what most folks think Jesus looked like bears little resemblance to what the genetics of the region at the time say he probably looked like.

The point here is that miracle are "good " events that are unlikely to happened . assume there a tree and this treee may lose a fruit that may fall. So we know that this fruit may have fall because of gravity vut is it still possible that all friuts fallen because of something else just because we know the explanation for some events it doesn't means it cant happen with no reason

@daniel: with that definition, it is impossible to argue that any given event is, or is not, a miracle.

Miracle has many meanings, the answer depends on the meaning
IF one takes the OT concept of miracle: that a God will reward/protect the virtuous, and smite the non-virtuous
then we have a long history of REALLY bad things happening to good people, and success accruing to very bad people, to consider this definition to be empirically falsified. This is uncontrolled data, but there is a LOT of it.
A variant on it, where faithfulness to a particular God is the source of success/failure, then I think we also have enough data to say that sufficient failures have happened to followers of every religion that the faithfullness variant is also empirically falsified.
If you are a reader of the OT, discussion of this is actually the point of the Book of Job, where Job challenges God to justify his misfortunes despite his virtue and faithfulness. His friends assume Job has some hidden faults that explain why God is now cursing him, after prior blessings.  God then answers, and says He does not need to answer to mere humans -- power allows Him to do anything he chooses, and moral questions of God are overruled by His power.  But then He blesses Job again.
Most of the rest of the OT involves prophets trying to explain the political and military failures of the Jews due to the much greater power of their Mesopotamian and Egyptian neighbors -- the Prophets' answer is that the nations of the Jews were not doctrinaire enough in implementing the LAW, else God WOULD have given them victory.  Theologically driven religious purity imposed on a society was their recommendation.  Most people today recognize this to be mere rationalization.
Most religious today take a smaller view of God's possible actions
30% of Americans consider they have experienced examples of miraculous events.  These are often clues, messages, sudden inspirations, seeing visions,  etc., which when acted upon lead to success in some small to medium aspect of their lives.
This sort of hint/clue interaction is more consistent with a Shamanistic or multi-spirit polytheistic worldview (like classical Greek theology with many lower level spirits as well as the Gods) than it is with the actions of an Omni-God, so there is a bit of a mismatch between these empirical examples and the theology they are used to support.
There are also lots of examples of hunches/inspirations that do not lead to success, and given the uncontrolled nature of this empirical data set, I would tend to conclude that no, it is not sufficient to determine if miracles of this type exist or not.  But making this set larger, would not change that.  Instead, one would need to find a way to gather better controlled data.
Gathering controlled data for/against psi phenomenon is the purpose pf parapsychology research.  PSI is "small" miracles, defined as being contrary to current physics theory
JB Rhine was the first implementer of lab-based PSI research.  His card-guessing experiments produced statistically significant results in 27 of 33 published papers up to 1940.
Research has continued on multiple other PSI phenomenon, with a mix of successes and failures (typical of science research).  The Parapsychology Association, an AAAS member society, notes that there is sufficient empirical evidence from large numbers of statistically significant test results to consider multiple PSI phenomena to be definitively demonstrated empirically to exist.  https://parapsych.org/articles/36/55/what_is_the_stateoftheevidence.aspx
Lab experiments may not qualify under your "affect history.  Medical benefits could
Medical research into miraculous healing has shown several statistically significant effects.  First, the "mind causal effect on matter" is strong enough from the placebo effect that one needs to have placebo controlled experiments. Under a pure physicalist POV, placebo is -- a challenge to explain away.
Therapeutic Touch, which is the medical name for laying on of hands, has a long history of evaluation.  Here is a skeptical report recommending more research:http://rationalmagic.com/RMS/rms-claman.PDF  from 1994.  Here are three meta analysis, which show increasing degrees of support for its medical effectiveness in the decades since:

https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/08943189922106413
https://www.internationaljournalofcaringsciences.org/docs/27_bassi_original_13_1.pdf
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41562-024-01841-8

If you want to discount the benefits of laying on of hands as somehow due to physical tough, not the agency of the toucher, then the meta analyses that show medical benefit from intentionality in non-contact settings and with animals or cell cultures should address that effort to dismiss medical miracles:

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25457442/

If you want to limit medical miracle evidence solely to prayer, and non contact settings, the evidence is suggestive that this does not work
The above studies used prayer as one instance of intentionality in healing, and included all sorts of non-prayer methods as well.  IF one limit studies to prayer alone, AND to distant non-contact settings, then the data to date tends to suggest weak to no effect:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/6343031_Prayer_and_Health_Review_Meta-Analysis_and_Research_Agenda

However, if prayer is evaluated in a less constrained way, with local as well as distant prayer, the results suggest a benefit:

https://nursing.ceconnection.com/ovidfiles/00005217-201312000-00009.pdf
https://www.mdpi.com/2077-1444/7/1/11

Wrap up
There is empirical evidence for discernable effects in our world from some definitions of miracle, and empirical evidence refuting this for other definitions of miracle.

Dcleve, would you like to answer this?

If you define a miracle as something unlikely happening, it should be fairly uncontroversial to say such things happen (well, the controversial part is calling it a "miracle"). This may also include an event or outcome that isn't necessarily unlikely, but it is merely one we like or prefer.
If you define a miracle as an action performed by some particular being that exists outside of space or time or whatever (possibly as proposed by some religion), then something being unlikely doesn't get you to that. One would first need to make a case that the existence of that being is coherent, possible, and likely, to then make the case that them existing and performing that action is a better explanation for the evidence than it happening to due mindless natural forces. But theists instead typically just focus on something being an unlikely result of natural forces (based on our limited knowledge) or us not knowing how something happened, and they treat that as proof of their god's existence.
The issue with discussions around "miracles" is the two definitions above are often used interchangeably and conflated with one another, yet they are very different.
The first definition, that something unlikely happened, is a mundane claim. Unlikely things happen all the time, because there are just that many things happening all the time. And often (always?) we're the ones assigning significance to a particular outcome: if you win the lottery, that would be really significant to you, but there are millions of people who didn't win. Someone winning the lottery is fairly unremarkable, and from an external point of view, it's not any more significant for the winner to be you, or for the winner to be anyone else.
* Technically speaking, it may be the case that there is a deterministic process, but it's too complex for us to predict what would happen, so we just assign some probability instead.
The second definition, that some supernatural being did something, is the questionable claim. We could potentially investigate that with science, but we haven't been able to verify any supernatural claims, and people keep pushing those claims to some point outside of what we can reliably observe, because it's either that or accepting that those claims are false, and many people are too attached to those claims to easily accept that they're false.


Other answers
Empirical evidence and the "demand" for empirical evidence

In the Bible, the source of Christian belief about miracles, they were never intended to be things which had any particular relationship one way or another with having their root causes identified empirically (this demand did not exist in that time before the Enlightenment movement)

Yes, the people from a few thousand years ago did indeed have rather poor epistemology, and could be convinced of practically anything. The enlightenment helped us realise that's not a good thing, and that just about the only reliable means of coming to beliefs is through empirical verification (we can include maths and logic, to some extent, in that).
In response, theists didn't offer any reason why we should think their method leads to truth, yet they keep advocating for using it, with no means of differentiating the wildly contradictory beliefs that method can lead to. Multiple contradictory religions say they got to their religion via "faith". People use "faith" to come to contradictory beliefs within the same religion, about e.g. what God did or what God wants. It's just not a good method, for anyone who cares about whether their beliefs are true.

Consider that if I were a man with a gun visiting an uncivilized population that had never heard of a gun. If I shot and killed somebody or something...

Uncivilised people will still see you holding and handling the gun, and then from that correlation, make an inference that the cause of the person dying is the gun.
If anything, this is a decent example to use AGAINST god claims, because it shows that we CAN empirically investigate things and their causes even when we don't understand them. That, in fact, is how we come to understand things generally. At first you don't understand, then you observe, hypothesise and experiment, and from that you determine causes.
But every time we tried to investigate a god claim, we have falsified or failed to verify it.
The inability for science to investigate god claims is mostly something theists insist on, but even their own commitment to that is doubtful. So many theists use the most dubious inferences to say that science proves God's existence (it's the essence of the teleological argument). Many theists clearly think that science and empirical evidence CAN investigate God's existence. I don't think that many of them truly believe the claim that science can't investigate God's existence. It's more that they "know" God exists, and science hasn't shown that, no matter how much people have tried to make it do that. So "obviously" science can't investigate God's existence. That's the only possible explanation, because they can't possibly be wrong about what they believe... right?
Theists have largely stopped making claims that we can empirically test about what gods do. They no longer say that gods cause lightning and rain, now that we've explained that with natural causes. They no longer say that supernatural entities cause and cure disease and illness, now that we've explained that with natural causes. Their claims about what sorts of prayers gods answer and how they do so get ever more vague and indistinguishable from things that happen naturally or randomly. Some go to the next step and say that God acts through natural causes, so they can keep saying God does all these things, but in the process rendering the God claim completely untestable, completely unnecessary, and fully indistinguishable from no god existing.
Side note: I remember once praying really hard to get a job. And I got it! Praise God! Well, I also went to a good school and university, have a rather strong aptitude for that career, did post-grad courses, did a ton of interview prep, unsuccessfully interviewed with the same company in the past, it's hardly a small company, and the job was probably one of the biggest catalyst that led to me questioning my beliefs and becoming an outspoken atheist (so... Praise the Flying Spaghetti Monster?!). But don't mind any of that. Just focus on the fact that I prayed, and then the thing I prayed for happened. Also don't mind any of the times when I prayed and the thing didn't happen. That doesn't mean prayer doesn't work, it just means God didn't want to give me that thing for some totally legit and totally real reason.
The efficacy of prayer and "parapsychology"

if prayer is evaluated in a less constrained way, with local as well as distant prayer, the results suggest a benefit

The effectiveness of prayer is mixed at best, as both papers recognise.
Under a physicalist view, we can trivially recognise that prayer works to a similar extent that meditating, listening to music, taking a warm bath or getting a massage (or "therapeutic touch") works. It serves to relax you (in one of various, completely natural, ways), and that has positive health effects. I certainly wouldn't call those things "miracles".
If one who wants to say prayer is some transcendent experience, possibly communicating with some invisible being, the challenge would be to eliminate the above possibility. To do that, you'd want to specifically EXCLUDE local prayer. And for purely remote prayer, the results are much more inconclusive and not distinguishable from random chance (of all the people who tried to test prayer, any positive results are undermined by poor methodology or counteracted by negative results).

[JB Rhine]'s card-guessing experiments produced statistically significant results in 27 of 33 published papers
[Editor note: initially presented as 37 of 40, which is an even higher 93%.]

There were 37 trials, which produced 558 hits out of 1850 trials. That's a 30% (558/1850) success rate. Or, going by the provided link, it's an even lower figure of 20% (489/2400). It's at least a little questionable to omit that number and just present that as 82% (27/33). Maybe that is technically correct, but a rate of 93% or 82% sure does look a lot more impressive than 20-30%, and one may wonder whether that's on purpose.
Also, they didn't even rule out the guy looking through the window to see which cards are picked. And someone claims to have inside information that they committed fraud.
Maybe they did, maybe they didn't. But let's remember that the burden of proof is on people claiming magic is real (and on people doing research to that effect), which may fundamentally change much of what we know about how reality works. And this is the best go-to example that is being offered? Come on now.

Research has continued on multiple other PSI phenomenon, with a mix of successes and failures (typical of science research)

There is no "mixed results" quite like pseudoscience* "research".
It's not "typical of science research" to get results that are as bad as prayer or "parapsychology" (... except in cases where the thing doesn't actually work).
Science gets a mix of successes and failures while we're trying to figure out what works or what's true. Once you have figured out what works, you (and anyone else) can reproduce that commonly upwards of 99% of the time (with some leeway for human error, device error or statistical variation). Because it works.
The above things haven't been able to achieve anywhere close to the same. It's an unreliable mess throughout.
* Me calling it "pseudoscience" is a value judgement / conclusion based on the abysmal research standards, the lack of reliable results and continued insistence that it's real even in spite of that. If someone were to say it's not pseudoscience because it's (controversially) a member of the AAAS, that is the exact wrong way to appeal to authority, and does nothing to address the actual reasons WHY I'm calling it pseudoscience (never mind that the very same organisation seems to classify that as pseudoscience itself).

an increasing number of parapsychologists are moving beyond proof-oriented research (feeling that psi has already been sufficiently proven for anyone willing to actually read and consider the experimental research)

To deal with the problem of a lack of reliable evidence, it's certainly one option to simply deny that there's any such problem by pointing to low-quality research, and move on.

@ user4894 Explaining unlikely events as natural processes is not inconsistent with "seeing the wonder of the world."

Big names in philosophy did not want to elaborate on miracles. It is left for street interpretation and urban legends.

Remember that the purpose of comments is to attempt to clarify the answer, not to argue with it. If you disagree, write your own answer, and let people vote on which one (s) they find useful

A comment about commenting?

@ScottRowe: granted, the meta comment could have just pointed to Meta.

@NotThatGuy would you like to answer this?

@user80226 Nah, other people would probably research that a lot better than I would, and would enjoy doing that more. Although a robust answer may involve a detailed literature review of all of whichever (?) research they may be alluding to. That may be quite a lot of work, unless there's already a meta-analysis. If that were a scientific article, you'd expect that claim to be backed up by a reference to some papers. You'd especially expect that in an answer to "What is the state-of-the-evidence", rather than their current answer of "trust me bro".

Note an AAAS member society is by definition not engaged in "pseudoscience".  The skeptic societies which deny the possibility of any evidence from parapsychology research, they are engaged in pseudoscience, per Popper's demarcation criteria.

The essence of a miracle lies in its very nature of being beyond explanation or proof. By the most practical definition, a miracle is an event attributed to a sentient force beyond our understanding, and therein lies its beauty and challenge. Our knowledge of the natural world is ever-evolving, and what seems inexplicable today might be clarified by science tomorrow. To claim that an unlikely event must be a miracle is to overlook the vast potential for future understanding. Thus, believing in miracles requires a leap of faith—a journey into mythos, where logic gives way to belief. It's an acceptance that, whether or not an event can be explained by natural phenomena now or in the future, the choice to see it as a miracle is deeply personal. In embracing this perspective, we see life itself as a miracle, a canvas where belief is a matter of choice, not proof. So, embrace what resonates with you, for belief is a personal journey, free from the confines of evidence.
Human knowledge isn’t infinite and that’s why the choice to believe in “miracles” is one that must be made on limited information or without even knowing if the information we have is true. So “miracles” may or may not exist and I don’t think we’ll ever have a definite answer.

It would really be a miracle if everyone accepted this point of view and just moved on! I would have no explanation for that.

The correct explanation for something "beyond explanation" is "I don't know". Your answer boils down to: "Every reliable way I can investigate this points to it being false, but I'll choose to keep believing it anyway". You can believe literally anything with "faith", which makes it a really poor method for coming to beliefs, if you care at all about whether your beliefs are true.

But if you really cared about whether your beliefs are true, then in almost all cases, "I don't know" is better.

@NotThatGuy In my best attempt to clarify what my answer was trying to say rather than; “Every reliable way I can investigate this points to it being false, but I'll choose to keep believing it anyway”; I believe it would be intellectually dishonest for me to convey that statement so for my purposes I was trying to convey; “I have no reliable to investigate these points therefore I will believe or I won’t”; I was answering the question of miracles in that anything inexplicable by humans, notwithstanding hypotheticals, could be explained in the future or could not so “miracles” only exist in us

@TristanOOF There is an all-powerful goblin named Roland that lives in my closet and disappears every time I open the door. Sometimes good things happen to me, and I believe he is responsible for that. I can't prove that he does or doesn't exist, or that he does any of the things I attribute to him, but I choose to believe it by faith. Is that reasonable? If not, what's the difference between that and positing some other sentient force beyond our understanding? I know my closet exists, for one thing - the same can't be said of wherever whichever deity exists.

"@NotThatGuy If you choose to believe that the goblin is responsible for all the good things in your life, by your criteria, the goblin becomes like a deity to you. In my previous comment, I aimed to express that, in the absence of reliable methods to investigate certain phenomena, people may choose to believe or not based on personal or cultural significance. For a Christian, criteria are the witnesses of Jesus, his teachings, personal experiences, and the Bible. In your case, if believing in the goblin is based on your personal criteria, then that forms your belief system or 'religion.'

@NotThatGuy the question is whether or not those good things are statistically make sense to happen

@TristanOOF My objection is you can believe literally anything with faith. My example with Roland was meant to demonstrate that. But you seem to just agree that anyone can indeed just insert whatever they want into any places we're unable to investigate (and you don't see the problem with that?). Does God e.g. tell you what's right and wrong, so you then refrain from doing certain things, tell others to refrain from doing certain things, and/or support laws to make things illegal? If so, and if you care about the well-being of yourself and others, you should want a better method than faith.

@NotThatGuy I see where you're coming from, but when I mentioned the goblin example as potentially forming a religion, I meant that if someone has a proper criterion for belief, then that's their framework. Who am I to say it doesn’t exist if they have a structured criterion for belief? If they were to present their criteria, I could critique it, and if my critique holds, then an intellectually honest person might reconsider their belief in the goblin. What I'm emphasizing is that the human mind has its limits, and I genuinely don't know if the goblin is real or not. Hope that helps clarify!

@TristanOOF That somewhat contradicts you saying it's about faith and belief that you're choosing, when there isn't evidence or proof. If someone has a "proper criterion for belief", that sounds like sufficient evidence or justification (which I wouldn't say Christianity has, but still). You could say you're using those together, but if a method that could get you to any conclusion is a bad method, and the evidence isn't good enough to support the conclusion by itself, combining the two doesn't get you to a well-supported conclusion.

@NotThatGuy I appreciate your thoughts, and I'd like to expand on what I mentioned earlier. While there isn't a definitive tool or formula to establish the absolute truth of a belief, we can still engage in a process of cross-applying evidence and establishing a criterion for belief. When I talk about faith and belief, I emphasize the importance of integrating personal experiences with the evidence. Faith, in this context, is not about accepting conclusions without question but rational belief which I believe is the basis of theology.

@NotThatGuy Imagine if a person had a dream in which a closet goblin told them to buy a lottery ticket, and then they actually won. For that person, this experience might serve as a powerful criterion for their belief. To them, this experience might feel like concrete evidence of the goblin's guidance or intervention. However, it's important to acknowledge that this criterion is open to critique. From an outside perspective, the lottery win could easily be attributed to chance, and the dream might be seen as a coincidence or a product of wishful thinking. This would be an example of faith.
